# Prefilter Quicksand Page - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter

Is there a way I can prefilter this page to solely show 'Applications'.

Like, if I visit http://razorjack.net/quicksand/demos/one-set-clone.html#app it would just show 'Applications'. Is this possible?

Googling around some people say this would help:

```
if(window.location.hash) {
                // run code here to filter the quicksand set
                var $filteredData = $data.find('li[data-type=' + window.location.hash + ']');
                $applications.quicksand($filteredData, {
                    duration: 800
                });
            }
```

but I've no idea where to use it.

**Many thanks for any help here** - truly stuck.

Comment: If you're trying to detect for a hash value on page load, this code simply needs to be placed ina  `$(document).ready(function(){`, with a conditional on the `else` of that statement to do `normal quicksand rendering`. This is all you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - and cool username ;-)
So, I'm basically looking to see if a hash exists, and if so, just displays those entries with that class name. Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //on page load, we check to see if a hash value exists.
   if(window.location.hash) {
       // run code here to filter the quicksand set
       var $filteredData = $data.find('li[data-type=' + window.location.hash + ']');
       $applications.quicksand($filteredData, {
           duration: 800
       });
   }else{
       // the page does not have a hash value. deliver normal content.
       $applications.quicksand('Your Normal Data Here', {
           duration: 800
       });
   }
});
```

This code only runs once the page has been prepared. It checks to see if the hash value is present. if so, it filters the data to `li` elements that have a `data type equal to the hash value`. Then it prepares quicksand to filter the data accordingly. If there is no hash value present, we load quicksand normally. I don't know what you do for your selector, so just replace `'Your Normal Data Here'` with whatever data filter you use.

It should be noted that as per the example, they are expecting you to have an `<li>` structure as follows ->

`<li data-type="data1"> //stuff </li>`

Where `data1` would be what the expected hash value is for filtering purposes.

Comment: Many thanks - will give this a quick try just now - and be back in a minute :)

Comment: i needed to strip the # off the front of window.location.hash like so: window.location.hash.substr(1) in my code (doubtless slightly different) tx muchly!